# General Half-life calculation for an abitrary nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, binding-energy, isotopes, half-life

I have been getting back into physics and I was wondering whether there was a generalized half-life equation for any given nucleus composition.

For instance for gold isotope 210-AU. Is it possible to calculate the half-life of this imaginary isotope by plugging in the protons and the neutrons?

If so what makes this difficult?

Looking forward to any reply

Comment: Are you looking for an empirical formula or something derived from first principles? Because the latter certainly doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it got me closer as your mentioning of the first principles brought up https://repository.tudelft.nl/islandora/object/uuid%3A2060cd8c-ada8-4d43-b799-d3ec146c228f and https://inspirehep.net/literature/1722854

Comment: There's something for alpha decay called the Geiger-Nuttall relation. It uses the $\alpha$'s KE, not $Z,\,A$. I'm unaware of analogous results for other decay paths.

Comment: I will look into it thanks I appreciate it!